# Can we set the content field in basic web content in Liferay using velocity language?

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm trying to achieve a web content display in Liferay that changes the "content" after a certain date. For instance from now till 04/05/2018 it shows "Hello world" but after that specified date it shows "Hola Mundo". Can it be achieved using the velocity script?I'm using Liferay 7.0

Comment: You can create number of web contents, drop them on similar page and schedule to appear / expire as per your requirement.

Comment: [**SCHEDULING WEB CONTENT PUBLICATION**](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/publishing-content-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
#if($date.get('yyyy-MM-dd') < '2018-05-04')
  Hello World
#else
  Hola Mundo
#end
```